# How to use an IoC Container?? I don't get it

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Here's what I know so far:

- DI lets me build reusable, unit-testable components
- DI is verbose because it requires that I explicitly set the dependencies (via constructor or method. I still don't understand the interface injection though). This is why a container or a service locator is needed.
- Container is better than service locator because classes won't need to be aware of the existence of it.

But I found these problems:

- Some classes will now depend from Container? If I don't use the default config for every class, as described in my services file, some classes will need to call the container to re-configure the needed object.
- On page 79 from this slide http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/dependency-injection-with-php-53, Fabien Potencier said that a Container does not manage all the objects, only those with a single instance (yet not singletons). I'm even more confused now.

Any help is greatly appreciated. =)

Answer (score 0):

> Some classes will now depend from Container?

No. That's why you use dependency injection as opposed to service location.

> On page 79 from this slide...

See page 82, it says "Unlike model objects". Honestly I'd never explain it like that ("Objects with only one instance (!= Singletons)" is either wrong or something very PHP specific, it doesn't apply to dependency injection or IoC+DI containers in general), but I bet what he was trying to explain is that the container usually manages service-like things, not model-like things.

Comment: If they don't depend from container, then how do they create childs with non-default configurations (ie: runtime defined settings) ?

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: it's the container who does all wiring and configuration. Individual classes *receive* dependencies and configuration.

Comment: Yea I know, but that works only for default object creation. What if at some point of the program execution (inside a child's child's child's method), for some reason, I need a say, DB_Cache dependency, instead of File_Cache ? I need to call the Container

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: nope, if a component needs a different implementation of some service, it's up to the container configuration to serve the correct implementation.

Comment: 1 - The Container reads the config file 2 - The Container wires everything up 3 - My app keeps executing, and at some point an 'if' statement is executed, and an instance of A or B is created. 4 - Container predicted the future so B (which I wanted) was already wired? Also, sometimes I may want to avoid instantiation (eiter of A or B) . I don't think this is going to work

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: In some situations you might want to inject a container-provided factory. But never the container itself.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: the last comment was a question out of the scope of the original question. Please create additional questions instead.

Comment: Out of scope? It wasn't even a question, I was just trying to make you understand my problem.

Yeah, injecting a factory seems to be the most common solution, but it feels like I wasn't using a container in the first place. Just good old GOF approach.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: it's not quite the same. I recommend getting a book on dependency injection.